# Geopandas intersects/contains fails between GeoDataFrames

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-relationship, geodataframe

I am struggling to make the GeoDataFrame functions: intersects/contains work between GeoDataFrames instances.

Let t be a GeoDataFrame with contents:

```
    id                                          geom
0  230  POINT (154860.3254511474 -468176.1141802836)
1  231  POINT (149247.4170036312 -436634.9002944119)
2  232  POINT (192530.4468407042 -465274.3331522844)
3  233  POINT (138125.4083732415 -419237.1333624315)
4  234  POINT (195314.0952219047 -468429.8881146177)
5  235  POINT (196320.0493430012 -479448.5877129403)
6  236  POINT (199780.1489409541 -446899.1169124786)
7  237  POINT (161437.1203666388 -440485.6615666826)
8  238  POINT (192413.1253873391 -465423.3888242305)
9  239  POINT (196039.9555616449 -473696.9492107867)
```

I extract the 5 last points in another GeoDataFrame named prt:

```
    id                                          geom
5  235  POINT (196320.0493430012 -479448.5877129403)
6  236  POINT (199780.1489409541 -446899.1169124786)
7  237  POINT (161437.1203666388 -440485.6615666826)
8  238  POINT (192413.1253873391 -465423.3888242305)
9  239  POINT (196039.9555616449 -473696.9492107867)
```

executing the command:

```
t.intersects(prt)
Out:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
```

However when I create a polygon from the points of prt and repeat the process it fails:

```
import shapely.geometry as sh
polygon = sh.polygon.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in prt.geometry.tolist()])

import geopandas as gpd
pds = gpd.GeoDataFrame([polygon], columns=['geom'], geometry = 'geom', crs = {'init':'epsg:3309'})


pds.geom_equals(polygon)
Out[873]: 
0    True
dtype: bool

t.intersects(polygon)
Out[875]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool

t.intersects(pds)
Out[874]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Can you please provide me some help/guidelines? I am pretty new in Python, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: Look at [How to find which points intersect with a polygon in geopandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440386) (the solution works with your data)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tested the code that was listed in the suggested link and it works. When I am trying it with my data it fails however. I tried additional relations, as well, such as within or contains (in order to avoid problems with the boundaries) but the result was the same.

Comment: Look below with your data

Answer (score 1):

With the solution of [How to find which points intersect with a polygon in geopandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440386) and your data

```
....
polygon = sh.polygon.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in prt.geometry.tolist()])
polygon.wkt
'POLYGON ((196320.0493430012 -479448.5877129403, 199780.1489409541 -446899.1169124786, 161437.1203666388 -440485.6615666826, 192413.1253873391 -465423.3888242305, 196039.9555616449 -473696.9492107867, 196320.0493430012 -479448.5877129403))'
t.intersects(polygon)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
pds = gpd.GeoDataFrame([polygon], columns=['geometry'], geometry = 'geometry', crs = {'init':'epsg:3309'}
t.intersects(pds.unary_union)
index_left
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
t.intersects(pds.geometry.ix[0]) 
index_left
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

And

```
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
sjoin(t, pds, how='inner')
    FID               geometry                         index_right
2    2  POINT (192530.4468407042 -465274.3331522844)            0
4    4  POINT (195314.0952219047 -468429.8881146177)            0
5    5  POINT (196320.0493430012 -479448.5877129403)            0
6    6  POINT (199780.1489409541 -446899.1169124786)            0
7    7  POINT (161437.1203666388 -440485.6615666826)            0
8    8  POINT (192413.1253873391 -465423.3888242305)            0
9    9  POINT (196039.9555616449 -473696.9492107867)            0
```